# Securepay payment received but Magento Order not created

Tags: mysql, magento

We have had an issue recently where a Securepay received the payment from a customer but the order was not created in Magento. The order ID was actually skipped also in Magento when the next order came through, but we cannot see it in the grid.

Can anyone shed some light on this on what might have happened?

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the order is in sales_flat_order table. Otherwise you can enable error logging and probably some php error happened after the request to payment gateway was made or user didn't came back with a response from payment gateway.